# How to set default value selected if i use ngModel, ngValue and how to add placeholder in select

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-ngmodel

How to set default value selected if i use ngModel, ngValue and how to add placeholder in select

```
<select [(ngModel)]="defaultSelect" (change)="onChangeGoods(query_param)" #query_param="ngModel" name="query_param" >
    <option [ngValue]="{'sortBy': 'price', 'sortOrder': 'asc'}" > От дешевых к дорогим</option>
    <option [ngValue]="{'sortBy':'price', 'sortOrder':'desc'}" > От дорогих к дешевым</option>
    <option [ngValue]="{'sortBy':'rating', 'sortOrder':'desc'}" > По рейтингу</option>
</select>
```

```
<select [(ngModel)]="goods_for_brands[i]" (change)="onChangeBrand(brand)" #brand="ngModel" name="brand" id="brand" >
    <option [ngValue] = ""  selected >choose BRAND</option>
    <option [ngValue]="good.brand" *ngFor="let good of goods_for_brands">{{good.brand}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have two `<select>`s. One has hard-coded `<option>` values and another using `*ngFor`. On which do you wish to apply your questions?

Comment: Where is the  hard-coded <option>, need to do selected and placeholder, where is *ngFor only placeholder. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a default value, you only need init the value with a init value.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="select" (ngModelChange)="onChangeGoods($event)" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
    <option [ngValue]="{ sortBy: 'price', sortOrder: 'asc' }">A</option>
    <option [ngValue]="{ sortBy: 'price', sortOrder: 'desc' }">B</option>
    <option [ngValue]="{ sortBy: 'rating', sortOrder: 'desc' }">C</option>
</select>
```

ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
    select = { sortBy: 'price', sortOrder: 'asc' };
    onChangeGoods(optionsValue: any) {}
    compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
        return c1 && c2  ? c1.sortBy === c2.sortBy && c1.sortOrder === c2.sortOrder  : c1 === c2;
    }
}
```

You can see I init the prop named `select` with a default value. Notice the `compareFn` function, your value is a object, so you should write a compare function and bind it to your select.

```
[compareWith]="compareFn"
```

You can see a demo below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8gsw9a?file=src/app/app.component.ts